# Cannot build Visual Studio 2017 project on a clean machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Clean Windows Server 2016 machine, I installed:

- Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017
  (https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15)
- .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack
  (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net452-developer-pack)

I got the following error message from MSBuild:

> [GetReferenceAssemblyPaths] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1124,
>   5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install
>   the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
>   application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
>   or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
>   from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
>   reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
>   targeted for the framework you intend.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Trying to install .NET Framework 4.5 I get this error:

> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating
>   system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5
>   redistributable.
>
> Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been
>   installed on this computer.

Trying to install .NET Framework 4.5.2 I get this error:

> .NET Framework 4.5.2 or a later update is already installed on this
>   computer.

Comment: `Version=v4.5` != `.NET Framework 4.5.2`

Comment: There is no way to install .NET Framework 4.5 today. Do you mean I should retarget the project to 4.5.2?

Comment: @abenci Have I answered your question? Please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017, you can choose components to install. If you run `vs_buildtools.exe` from `cmd`, it only installed minimal MSBuild toolset.

You can choose components to install via GUI:

[image: Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 — Individual components]

---

Also, you can install particular component or workload via `cmd`:

> vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack --passive

You can find workloads and component names here: [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools)

Detailed info about command-line parameters are here: [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio)

---

You can consider installing only workloads required for you (with recommended components):

> vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --includeRecommended --passive

or all of them

> vs_buildtools.exe --allWorkloads --includeRecommended --passive

---

You can use `--quiet --wait` keys instead of `--passive` to make installation silent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running `MSBuild` from the wrong directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\**amd64**\

Try and run MSBuild.exe from the `bin` instead and see if that works:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

Comment: Nothing to do, I always get: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targe
ts(1124,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resol
ve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the
framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed...`

Comment: Try [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).  Ensure that `.NET Framework 4.5 Software Development Kit` is checked during installation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open visual studio installer
2. click the "modify" button under your VS installation,
3. In the summary, expand the ".NET desktop development" category
4. tick ".NET Framework 4-4.6 development tools
5. You may also want to tick the rest of the optional parts.
6. press the "modify" button to begin installation

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot build Visual Studio 2017 project on a clean machine

You can not install the .NET framework 4.5 on that machine, because you have a higher version of .NET framework 4.5.2 installed.

To resolve this issue, you can retarget the project to 4.5.2 or you can uninstall the .NET framework 4.5.2 and install the .NET framework 4.5.

[Install .NET Framework 4 (or 4.6) in Windows Server 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1183705/install-net-framework-4-or-4-6-in-windows-server-2016)